# Firebase Cloud Message Action after clicked the notification in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implement Firebase SDK in Unity. Sending a notification to device is working fine. But can I control which view application will open after the user clicked the notification?

> for example:
>
> 1) Send notification message through Firebase console or user HTTP API
>   (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)
>
> 2) Register device will received notification.
>
> 3) By default, application will launch after user click the
>   notification. But now what I needed is application launch and bring
>   the user to setting or other view after user click the notification.

How can I make this app flow behavior?

Sorry for my english. hope your all understand what I'm means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd love some tips for this as well!